# Create a non-manifold assembly

Tags: faces

I realize this seems strange, but I WANT to create a non-manifold assembly from multiple parts. I want all of the parts in my completed model to have shared surfaces with other parts. Does anyone know of a way to do this in Blender?

Comment: maybe add example images/skeches, so we can understand what you mean?

Comment: Nothing in Blender prevents you from doing this? Can you cite an example where this has been a problem?